# How to properly extend a class with TypeScript in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript1.6

I want to use TypeScript in a NodeJS environment. Since I'm absolutely new to TypeScript I'm not sure how to extend classes properly with the NodeJS module system.

---

I want to extend my class `Champion` with `GameObject`.

#### GameObject.ts

```
///<reference path="../../typings/node/node.d.ts"/>

class GameObject {
    id:number;
    name:string;
}

module.exports = GameObject;
```

#### Champion.ts

```
///<reference path="../../typings/node/node.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="Image.ts"/>
///<reference path="GameObject.ts"/>


class Champion extends GameObject {
    // ...
}

module.exports = Champion;
```

This throws no compilation error so far.

Now I want to create an instance of my Champion. This is what I've tried

```
// I tried referencing the Champion.ts which haven't changed anything
var Champion = require('../api/types/Champion');
var c = new Champion();
```

My `Champion.js` now throws the following error:

> ReferenceError: GameObject is not defined

So I thought I need to `require('GameObject')` in `Champion.ts` which make my application running. But I get another error.

Either I reference and `require` my `GameObject`

```
///<reference path="GameObject.ts"/>
var GameObject = require('./GameObject');
class Champion extends GameObject {
```

Which gives me the error

> Duplicate Identifier GameObject

Or I just `require` and get

> Type any is not a constructor function type

#### TypeScript Version

```
$ tsc -v
message TS6029: Version 1.6.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `module.exports = GameObject;` with `var/require` use `import/require`

This will give you type safety on the import side. These are called file modules and documented here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html